# Lightning-Checkbox-Group Undefined Promise Error when using Template Syntax

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am receiving the following error when using a Lightning Checkbox Group:

[image]

I am puzzled because my getter function is clearly getting called per the `console.log` statement in line 4 of languageSelectionChild.js? Am I missing something?

## JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class LanguageSelectionChild extends LightningElement {
  @api languageSelection;

  get languageOptions() {
    console.log(`languageOptions called`);
    //values are OHT api code
    return [
      { label: "Russian", value: "ru-ru" },
      { label: "Serbian", value: "sr-rs" },
      { label: "Albanian", value: "sq-al" },
      { label: "Indonesian", value: "id-id" },
      { label: "Ukrainian", value: "uk-ua" },
      { label: "Macedonian", value: "mk-mk" },
      { label: "French", value: "fr-fr" },
      { label: "Spanish", value: "es-es" }
    ];
  }

  //adds the event value to the language slection array.
  handleLanguageChange(event) {
    this.languageSelection = event.detail.value;
    console.log(this.languageSelection);
  }
}
```

## HTML

```
<template>
  <template if:true={languageOptions}>
    <div class="slds-col slds-p-around_small">
      <lightning-checkbox-group
        name="languages"
        label="Select Languages"
        value={languageSelection}
        options={languageOptions}
        onchange={handleLanguageChange}
        style="padding-left: 100px;"
      ></lightning-checkbox-group>
    </div>
  </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `languageSelection` variable is null, resulting in the error. The minimum to fix this problem is:

```
@api languageSelection = [];
```

Here's the [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/C6AtmQCKV/1/edit) for this.

Comment: +1 I just wrote exact same answer fully and just discarded it seeing your answer. haha